# Implementing custom object for HashSet

Tags: c#, hash, hashcode, hashset

I'm making use of HashSet's for algorithmic purposes, but I am having problems with the implementation of "custom objects". Doing some research it appears one should:

- Override Equals and GetHashCode ([previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081595/c-sharp-defining-hashset-with-custom-key))
- Should not generate hashcodes with mutable objects ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110376/hashset-contains-problem-with-custom-objects) yes it's Java, but I figured the implementation was close enough)

---

My Implementation:

```
//Simplified version of actual class with key components
class customObject {
    public readonly uint column;
    public readonly char row;

    public customObject(uint column, char row) {
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return obj is customObj && !ReferenceEquals(this, obj);
    }

    /*where uint column and char row are readonly. HashSet add is not called
    until these variables are set with their lifetime value.*/
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        unchecked {
            var hashCode = row.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ column.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}

//somwhere else
HashSet<customObject> s = new HashSet<customObject>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(char c = 'A'; c < 'J'; c++) {
        s.add(new customObject((uint)i,c));
    }
 }
```

---

Unfortunately, I am unable to add my custom object to the HashSet. As I can confirm the `count` of items in the HashSet is 0 after attempting to add the object. Since there are no items in the set I suspect that I am missing something in the implementation, but have been unable to find a complete answer/tutorial regarding prepping custom objects for use in HashSets.

Comment: first your `Equals` is wrong . Second it's hard to see the problem with your Hashset when you don't post the code for this as well (and btw: add the definition of your object here too ... for example: *what* is `row`?)

Comment: The code looks OK (except I'm not sure why your `ReferenceEquals` is negated). How are you adding the object to your `HashSet`? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: @vesan I'm adding with set.add(obj)

Comment: please post **real** *working* code...

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The reason why your `HashSet` is empty is almost certainly unrelated to the code you have posted, unless your `GetHashCode` method throws an exception.

Comment: @vesan I was looking more to check my steps as far as went for the customObject, so I originally didn't think a working example would be necessary. I have revised "my implementation" section to more reflect my situation.

Comment: 1. Your code does not compile. 2. `for(char c = 'A'; c < 'A'; c++)` will never enter the loop, as C will never be < 'A'.

Comment: @vesan that was a typo, that should be some other greater value. That wasn't causing the issue unfortunately.

Comment: 1. Your code still does not compile. 2. If I fix all syntax errors, it works as expected. Post the _actual_ code you are running that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(char c = 'A'; c < 'A'; c++)
```

The debugger is your friend; check your loop condition.  That loop body will never run.  Also, your implementation of `GetHashCode` would never cause `Count == 0` after adding your object with no exception being raised.  Lastly, your implementation of `Equals` is wrong.

It assures that the same object reference will *not* be considered equal and, if you're going for reference equality, then you don't need to override it in the first place.

Comment: The c < 'A' was a mistake, I meant to paste another greater value. The loop logic is unfortunately not the problem in my code.

Comment: so your real problem is **still** that you don't want to show the actual code?